# Determine all the homomorphisms $\varphi:\Bbb Z_4 \to S_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

> Determine all the homomorphisms $\varphi:\Bbb Z_4 \to S_3$.

As $\Bbb Z_4$ is generated by $\langle 1 \rangle$ and since $\varphi(g^k)=\varphi(g)^k$ I have that $\varphi(1+1+1+1)=\varphi(0)=(1)$ since the homomorphism must map the identity to the identity.

It seems that I would need to figure out where $\varphi$ maps $1$. Since $\varphi(1+1+1+1)=\varphi(1)\varphi(1)\varphi(1)\varphi(1)=(1)^4$ but I'm a bit confused here. Should I find an element of $S_3$ for which multiplied by itself $4$ times I'll get the identity or what?

Comment: Compare, say, with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857550/how-many-homomorphisms-from-z4-to-s4).

Comment: Hello Samuel. You can try to prove the following thing: let $Exp(4,S_3)$ (the notation is not standard) be the set of elements in $S_3$ whose fourth power is the identity; then the map sending any morphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow S_3$ to $\phi(1)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Your approach gets off to a good start.  Remember, though, that not all homomorphisms are isomorphisms.

Comment: The order of the image must divide both $3!$ (why?) and $4$ (why?). So, we are left with two cases, only; the first is (the) trivial (one); the second corresponds to the kernel $\{0,2\}$ and then to an image isomorphic to $C_2$ (or $\Bbb Z_2$, if you prefer).